# C++ in the cloud. Casablanca REST Service on Microsoft Azure

Tags: c++, rest, azure, visual-studio-2013, casablanca

Hello fellow Azure users. I have created quite an extensive C++ REST service using the CasaBlanca REST SDK. When I began working on this project I as lead to believe that I could run it in the Cloud (Azure) . Please explain how best I can get this service to run on Microsoft Azure. I can't afford to re-program the entire project in another language like C# or Java. Thanks in advance!

If you're wondering why I believed CasaBlanca was meant for the Cloud:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Australia/2012/AZR331

-Seth

Comment: If you haven't used casablanca you wouldn't know what it does. It is a REST SDK so you get Http_Listeners for listening and Http_Clients for calling other restful services which return json. I'm strictly using my service for the Listener part which allows me to return Json code when a POST or GET or PUT etc is called on the corresponding URL that I'm listening on.

Comment: were you able to figure it out? I am facing same issue with VS2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the TechEd video I can see that they are using the SpeechService demo which you can find the source of here: https://hg.codeplex.com/microsoftcasablanca so you can understand how they performed the deployment to Azure.

Looking at the code I can see the solution is designed to be deployed to a [Cloud Service Worker Role](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-what-is/) and includes a "Cloud Service" project in the Visual Studio solution - this is the project type which gives the "Deploy To Cloud" option which you see in the video.

Given that the demo is from 2012 there will have been many Azure SDK releases since then so the demo code may require an update, but the deployment method from Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 remains essentially unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful reply. I see no option for creating a CasaBlanca cloud service worker role. In the video it is plainly listed under "Other languages -> Visual c++ -> Casablanca azure cloud service" etc. I'll look over the speech to try and understand the deployment process.

Comment: Recommend you download the sample from Codeplex and see how it works.  It may be, as you said, that this option has since been removed (or was only present during preview).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless how you're using casablanca, c++ applications can be run on Virtual Machines, web/worker role (stateless) VMs in cloud services, probably websites... Choosing between these is a matter of opinion (or at least dependent on the app you're building), and there's no single right answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Currently it seems very hard to run c++ on a azure vm. It requires statically compiling your application so it includes all the libraries and their dependencies. Also it requires (to my understanding) a c# program to start the c++ program. I was only wondering (as you would see in the video) a simple way of deployment. In the video he creates a "c++ azure service" and for deployment he right clicks on the app in the solutions explorer and clicks "deploy to cloud" . That was in 2012. They must of removed the ability in a future release.